# C++ | Can't add items to class member vector

Tags: c++, vector

I've got this class:

```
class CAppFramework : public IBaseApp
{
public:
     CAppFramework( std::initializer_list< CClientApp* > input );
     CAppFramework( );
     ~CAppFramework( );

     void Create( ) override;
     void Release( ) override;

     std::vector< CClientApp* > GetClientApps( );

private:
     std::vector< CClientApp* > m_ClientApps;
};
```

When I try to add an item to the m_ClientApps vector like this:

```
int main( )
{
     CAppFramework appframework = CAppFramework( );
     appframework.GetClientApps( ).push_back( new CTest( ) );

     appframework.Create( );
     appframework.Release( );

     return 0;
}
```

It fails. The size of the vector remains 0.

However if I add items like this:

```
int main( )
{
     CAppFramework appframework = CAppFramework( { new CTest( ) } );

     appframework.Create( );
     appframework.Release( );

     return 0;
}
```

The item is getting added successfully. Why is that?
I hope someone can help me out.

Bye and have a nice day!

Comment: `GetClientApps` returns a copy when it should be returning a reference.

Answer (score 1):

```
std::vector< CClientApp* > GetClientApps( );
```

This returns the vector **by value**. A copy of the vector is actually made, for the return value from this function.

```
appframework.GetClientApps( ).push_back( new CTest( ) );
```

This `push_back()`s a new value into a vector object that gets returned, which is a copy of the original vector, a temporary value that gets immediately destroyed at the end of this expression. The `push_back()` accomplishes nothing useful.

You need to return the vector by reference, rather than value:

```
std::vector< CClientApp* > &GetClientApps( );
```

Comment: You don't happen to be, by chance, someone with Java background that's trying to learn C++? If that's the case, you need to quickly un-learn everything you know about objects in Java. Otherwise, you'll keep coming back here...

Comment: Yeah I come from java :|. Ye it's pretty unfortunate that I learned it before.

Comment: It's much easier to learn Java when you already know C++, than the other way around.